# Как вывести значения JSON из консоли в область на сайте?

Tags: javascript, html, json

```js
 success : function(json) {
                  console.log(json)
                  let json = {"companies" : ['test1', 'test2', 'test3']};
                  document.getElementById('companies').innerHTML = json.companies.join(', ');

                  },

                  // handle a non-successful response
                  error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {

                  }
```

```html
<div class="leadOut">
  <p>Подходящие компании</p>
</div>
```

Как вывести значения JSON о компаниях которые выводятся в консоль?

```js
function select_company()
{
  var chbx_list = collect_checkboxes();
  var amount = chbx_list.length;
  console.log(chbx_list);
  csrf_token = $('input[name="csrfmiddlewaretoken"]').val();
  $.ajax({
      url : "/blockchain/", // the endpoint убрать первыйс слуеш в случае неудачи
      type : "POST", // http method
      data : {chbx_amount : amount,
              checks_list : chbx_list,
              csrfmiddlewaretoken: csrf_token }, // data sent with the post request

              success : function(json) {
                  console.log(json)
                  },

                  // handle a non-successful response
                  error : function(xhr,errmsg,err) {

                  }
      });
      return false;
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Завит от того, куда выводить: в div, в select, в textarea, в dropdown, в canvas нарисовать, на графике показать, бегущей строкой сделать и пр

Comment: Выводить в блок div (подходящие компании)

Comment: Что есть "подходящие компании"?

Comment: Так выглядит блок куда выводить
<div class="leadOut">
  <p>Подходящие компании</p>
</div>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам подойдёт метод **[join()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)** для массивов, который объединяет все элементы массива в строку с помощью указанного разделителя

```js
let json = {"companies" : ['test1', 'test2', 'test3']};

document.getElementById('companies').innerHTML = json.companies.join(', ');
```

```html
<div class="leadOut"> 
    <p>Подходящие компании:</p> 
    <div id="companies"> </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Не совсем понимаю в какую часть кода такое вставляется?
После выполнения функции или где то в ней?

Comment: @АлексейРешетило в callback функцию `success`, где сейчас у вас написано `console.log(json)`

Comment: эх, KeyError выдаёт,хотя есть вероятность, что не правильно размещаю

Comment: @АлексейРешетило так вы соблюдайте правильностью ключей. я не уверен что я правильно написал. может у вас просто `json.join(', ')`;

Comment: Если хочешь чему-то научиться, то будь готов быть идиотом, с этим лозунгом я спрошу правильно ли размещаю. Приложил код

Comment: @АлексейРешетило не совсем правильно)) потому что моя строка `let json = {"companies" : ['test1', 'test2', 'test3']};` лишь для примера. у вас же её не будет. вам надо оперировать сразу с `json` из ответа.........Также прошу заметить, что я в Html добавил дополнительный `div` с `id=companies`

Comment: Див допер добавить ахах)

Comment: @АлексейРешетило в принципе теперь должно сработать вот это: `success : function(json) {
                  document.getElementById('companies').innerHTML = json.companies.join(', ');
                  },`

Comment: Сработало, спасибо большое!!!!